# --storage.tsdb.retention.size in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I wanted to try the feature of storage.tsdb.retention.size in Prometheus 2.12.

My configuration for prometheus retention is 90days or 2GiB. My expectation was when the size of prometheus data directory crosses 2GiB, it will start deleting data. However, its at 9GB now, I can recover the oldest data.

PS: Have read https://www.robustperception.io/configuring-prometheus-storage-retention and https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/

Am i missing something in my understanding?

Also on setting storage.tsdb.retention.size as 2GB, the runtime configs shows the retention size to be 2GiB, why the difference in units?

Answer (score 2):

From https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/

> --storage.tsdb.retention.size: [EXPERIMENTAL] This determines the maximum number of bytes that storage blocks can use (note that this does not include the WAL size, which can be substantial). The oldest data will be removed first. Defaults to 0 or disabled. This flag is experimental and can be changed in future releases. Units supported: KB, MB, GB, PB. Ex: "512MB"

If I read the definition of a storage block correctly: it is the max size of a collection of metrics (a block), excluding WAL and compaction files. It might be that there are multiple blocks.

Also it might depend on whether a big portion of the used diskspace is used by WAL files, as the documentation mentioned these are not compacted yet and relatively big.

You might want to check the size of the wal directory. Also: if there are multiple blocks , are those blocks limited to 2GB? 
If my understanding is correct, they can be smaller, as a new block is created per 2 hours.